# Problem when importing gurobi through httpd

Tags: python-3.x, httpd.conf, gurobi

I successfully configured gurobi on centos 7 and it works if I try gurobi_cl on a test.lp file where the test.lp file contains just one line:
Minimize

Now i try to import gurobi from a script that is launched from httpd an I get this error:
From gurobi import *
File"/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gurobipy/**init**.py" line 1 in 
From .gurobi import *
ImportError: libgurobi90.so: cannot open shared object file:
No such file or directory

I am using gurobi9.0.1 and python 3.7 and I don't know why gurobi is calling python 2.7 in the log below.

Could you please help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solved the problem. I had to add gurobi_pi.conf under old.so.conf containing the path to my gurobi folder

- ldconfig